# Am I able to send and receive data via the same UDP socket simultaneously

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

Am I able to send and receive data (therefore, to use `sendto` and `recvfrom` methods) via the same UDP socket simultaneously in Python?

I need to listen for new packets while sending some data to previous clients from another thread.

Comment: Sure - it will work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, UDP sockets are bidirectional.